Is there any way to know in Vim from which file and in which line number a function is called?
If I call a function in Vim p.e. :call myfunction() I would like to know from which file and in which line number this function is called, is that possible? (The source code)
In Python the inspect (currentframe) module exists, is there something similar in Vim?
# to find caller of a function
def myfunction(message):
    from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo
    print(getframeinfo(currentframe()).filename + ':' + str(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno) + ' - ', message)

How can I know in Vim from which file and in which line number a function is called?

Use :help :throw to throw an error and see a trace.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't return the line in the file where the function is invoked but the line under "Try" within the function.

This is not possible from vim as far as I know. So you will need a work-around.
For such purpose it's good to have tmux installed on the device where you are working at and you can open multiple tabs inside tmux. You could have the 0'th tab not having opened any files and the further tabs could be for opened files via vim. So, if you wonder where myfunction is defined, then simply switch to the 0th tab via
Ctrl + b + 0

and run
grep -rn '.' -e "def myfunction"

and you will get the file(s) and line number(s) as well.
Surely, it's not a vim solution per se, because there is no vim solution, as vim is a text editor and if you opened a different file, it will not find your match in the other file, but there is a nice vim-tmux configuration that you can set up easily for yourself that will be very close to it in look n feel.

Buffer, its filename and cursor position don't change simply because a function is called. They're available using the usual calls: expand('%') to get the current filename; col('.') to get the cursor's column; line('.') to get the cursor's line number.

line(“.”) and col(“.”) give the information of the file I am in at that moment.
What I want to know is if I call a function from another file like menu.vim (via the menu) or in _vimrc, in which line and file the call function is invoked.

@Reman Source code file/line? You should better explain that in the question. And no, I don't know any way to get to the source code. Most probably, there is no way.

You can try to throw an exception and use code like LineNumber() to parse v:throwpoint but it doesn't give you a stack of calls, only the current exception.
